# Visual Studio 2019: Quick Watch: dictionary key names are not displayed instead "Value" is shown as the "key name" for all keys

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am unable to see the key(string type) names in quick watch. Does anyone has any idea what's missing? It was working before and suddenly it isn't. 
**Solution Tried**:- Updated the visual studio version to the latest.
Visual studio 2019:-  Version 16.5.4
I am using a dictionary
Issue is still persisting. 
  
[image: Quick watch snippet]

Comment: What is type of key? working for me on VS 2019 16.5.4 & earlier too, also try expanding values on left

Comment: It's a **dictionary<string, object>**.
It does work for my colleagues using same version. There are 2 of us facing the same issue.